# Referencing another preference in onPreferenceChange(preference, value)

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have two preferences that are related (`units` and `distance`)
When `units` changes I want to convert the `distance` accordingly. For example if `distance` is **1610** meters and `units` changes to **miles** I want to convert it to **1** mile.

For this I use the code provided by Android studio SettingsActivity code.
But how do I find the `distance` preference when the `units` preference changes?

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        ...
        // I need to address also the distance preference value here
        // It is not the preference given in the arguments (units) 
        // The distance preference is in another preferences fragment
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: I so far tried : `preference.getPreferenceManager().findPreference(<other_preference_key>)` but it does not work if the other preference is on a different fragment

Comment: I decided to ditch the multi fragment approach and went back to using only one fragment for all preferences, grouped by categories. As I said in the previous comment, when all preferences are in the same fragment I can access them from one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put it in the listener you can just override the `onSharedPreferencesChanged()` method and access like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(String str, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit()
editor.putInt("distance", 1610)
editor.apply()
```

Otherwise use an application context from a singleton.

**Update in response to comment**:
My apologies for misunderstanding your question. In that case something like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
int distance = prefs.getInt("distance", defaultValue);
preference.setSummary(/* whatever value you wish to pass*/);
```

Comment: Well, your suggestion is not 100% a solution for me, because I not only need the value of the `distance` preference, but also to change the summary and dialog message (it is an `EditTextPreference`)

Comment: Updated the answer, if this is still off topic please leave another comment and I will delete it.

Comment: Your answer is not off topic. It just solves half my problem (haven't checked it yet) I also need to get the `EditTextPreference` for distance and change the dialog message. Don't delete it, there is always someone who can learn from it.